# MongoDB Nested Query taking too long to execute

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate, query-optimization

I have a collection with millions of documents, I'm trying to fetch all these table records at the same time. I have used cursor for execution.

My MongoDB Query looks like this, I'm trying to get data from multiple collection here. But it's taking almost a minute to fetch one data, is there any way I can optimize this ?

```js
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "product_id": "155",
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Myusers",
      "let": {
        "localField": "$userId"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": [
                "$_id",
                "$$localField"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "Market",
            "let": {
              "userId": "$_id"
            },
            "pipeline": [
              {
                "$match": {
                  "$expr": {
                    "$and": [
                      {
                        "$eq": [
                          "$userId",
                          "$$userId"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "$eq": [
                          "$event_id",
                          155
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "$lookup": {
                  "from": "member_groups",
                  "localField": "groups",
                  "foreignField": "_id",
                  "as": "groups"
                }
              }
            ],
            "as": "market"
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "Myusers"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$Myusers"
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "finalData": [
        {
          "$skip": 0
        },
        {
          "$limit": 1
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "userId": "$Myusers._id",
            "community": "$Myusers.market",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "finalData": "$finalData",
    }
  }
]
```

How can I optimize this aggregate query here?

Comment: Do you have an index on `"product_id"`? Do you have an index on `"userId"` in the `Market` collection?  Does the query in this [mongoplayground.net pipeline](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hlt654imhDT) work?  Is it more performant?

Comment: yes @rickhg12hs

Comment: What is "too long"? How fast would you like it to execute? What is the purpose of the `$facet` here? Please upload (or link to) the `.explain("executionStats")` output for this aggregation

Comment: @naive_user Yes to all 4 questions?  Is the pipeline performant enough now?